# How to display text from an XML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, get

I have a page that is supposed to display a company/companies based on the location of the visitor. I used a plug-in to determine the visitor's location. The companies list is stored in an XML file with the following set-up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Events>
  <EventItem>
    <Country>Abu Dhabi</Country>
    <Company>Trizac Abu Dhabi</Company>
    <Address>P.O. Box 4434 Abu Dhabi U.A.E.</Address>
    <Email Link="ahmad.nabulsi@trizac.ae"><![CDATA[ahmad.nabulsi@trizac.ae]]></Email>
    <Web Link=""><![CDATA[]]></Web>
    <Phone Link="tel:971 2 633 0552"><![CDATA[Phone:971 2 633 0552]]></Phone>
    <Fax Link="tel:971 2 633 0557"><![CDATA[Fax:971 2 633 0557]]></Fax>
  </EventItem>
</Events>
```

I used the following code to display the data (I placed them in alerts first)

```
$.get(strXML, function(d){
                alert("Start search in : " + strXML + " for " + location.countryName); 
                $(d).find("Country:contains('Hong Kong')").each(function(){
                    var $lbp = $(this);
                    alert ($lbp.find("Company").text() + " hello " + $lbp.find("Address").text())
                }); //end of $(d).find
            }); //end of $.get
```

I hardcoded location.countryName first (in this case, "Hong Kong" because my locator puts the country name in all caps, while the data in XML are in camel caps(I'm still trying to find out how to change that). In my XML, there's one company in HK, and the codes see that. But when I try to display the texts in the  and  tags, it just displays nothing.

That's why I placed a " hello " there just to see if the alert code is working at least. It is, but it's not displaying anything for the company and address :(

I also tried "Japan", it has four companies, and I get four alerts in the process, but I can't seem to diplay the data from the XML tags :( Help is greatly appreciated :) I'm new to this jQuery/XML combo, so please bear with me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've done a `find()` to get the `<Country />` tag, then you're looking inside that for the Country again, which isn't there. Instead you need to go up a level. Try this:

```js
$.get(strXML, function(d){
    alert("Start search in : " + strXML + " for " + location.countryName); 
    $(d).find("Country:contains('Hong Kong')").each(function(){
        var $lbp = $(this).closest('EventItem'); // Note the parent is selected here
        alert ($lbp.find("Company").text() + " hello " + $lbp.find("Address").text())
    });
});
```

Comment: You are a life saver!!!! Thank you so much! That worked :) I'll save this one handy :) Thanks so much :)